# Object lock is not working for Thread Safety

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I was testing thread-safety for better grasp and this is what I did :

I have a Type called `ThreadSample` which has two methods and this where locking is happening :

```
internal class ThreadTime
    {

        public void doSomething(string message)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                DialogResult t = MessageBox.Show(message);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }

        public void anotherLife(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is coming from anotherLife method and and current threadNumber is " + message);
        }
    }
```

Basically the idea is when `doSomething()` is called, it should lock the entire objects and other threads can even invoke `anotherLife` method since they are waiting for other threads to release the lock.

This is the logic to simulate lock-release :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ThreadTime time;
    private Thread thread;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(workerThread));
        time = new ThreadTime();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread.Start();
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        time.anotherLife("Current thread is = " + "UI Thread");  
    }

    private void workerThread()
    {
        //time.doSomething("Current thread is = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        time.doSomething("Worker Thread");
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code right below :

When `Form` is being initialized, a new `Thread` and `ThreadSample` are created. Then when user clicks on the `button1`, thread is started and the UIThread is reaching and invoking `anotherLife` which is not thread-safe at first.

Anyways, the output is :

- There are two MessageBox shown at the same time.

What I was expecting is when the new Thread invokes `doSomething()`, it gets the lock of the object and `UIThread` waits for the lock to be released to be able to invoke `anotherLife` method.

Can some one explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: Why have you got the java tag when this is clearly C#? And why are you using Java naming conventions in C#?

Comment: The way I read your question, it sounds like you have some incorrect idea on how locks work. A lock on a object is just a token to synchronize on. Nothing happens to the lock object itself.

Comment: Maybe the Java tag refers to the conventions rather than the language?

Comment: @Jon Skeet : I've been learning Java as a c# developer. What've I been reading shows me that all I have to do use synchronized keyword instead of lock to make it java so I think I may also need help of java developers.

Comment: Braveyard, that is a bit too simplistic. Better scrap the Java tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I was expecting is when the new Thread invokes doSomething(), it gets the lock of the object and UIThread waits for the lock to be released to be able to invoke anotherLife method.

UIThread won't wait for a lock to be released before allowing `anotherLife` to proceed because `anotherLife` is not performing a lock.  Both threads have to run into a `lock` statement (locking on the same object) in order to get the behavior you're looking for.  Try modifying it to something like:

```
public void anotherLife(string message)
{
    lock (this) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is coming from anotherLife method and and current threadNumber is " + message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `lock(this)`  or `lock(someThing)` can be a bit of a misleading metaphor.

There is nothing being done 'to' `this`, but rather the argument to `lock` is used as a token. All threads accessing a specific resource must use the same token (object) to request access, otherwise your code is broken.

That is why frequently a helper object is used:

```
private List<string> myList = ...;
private object myLock = new object();

lock(myLock)
{
   myList.Add("foo");
}
```

This scheme only works if all threads lock on `myLock` before changing `myList`.
It is considered a 'best practice` because it is not guaranteed that a List<> is safe to lock on.

Answer (score 1):

Only your thread observes the lock

You need to change

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread.Start();
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        time.anotherLife("Current thread is = " + "UI Thread");  
    }
```

to

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread.Start();
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
lock(time)
{
        time.anotherLife("Current thread is = " + "UI Thread");  
}
    }
```

Based on your code, it seems you think putting a lock on an object means that object can't be accessed by anything else. That is not the case. A lock on an object just means *another* lock may not be put on the object until the first lock is released.

You access the object from two places in your code, one in the thread and the other in the button event. You need a lock in both places.

Comment: This is one neat explanation. Especially the last second paragraph. +1 thanks.